# Как подсчитать количество цитирований в таблице комментариев?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Имеется таблица комментариев, которая выглядит следующим образом:

| ID | Created date | Text | Post_ID | User_ID | Parent_Comment_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | comment1 | 1 | 1 | null |
| 2 | ... | comment2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | ... | comment3 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | ... | comment4 | 1 | 4 | null |
| 5 | ... | comment5 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 6 | ... | comment6 | 1 | 2 | 4 |

Нужно посчитать, сколько было цитирований (ответов на комментарии пользователя) для каждого пользователя.

Для указанной таблицы и данных результат должен выглядеть так:

| User_ID | Quotes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 |

Как я понимаю, это нужно реализовывать при помощи иерархического запроса, но как именно это сделать - не понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как я понимаю, это нужно реализовывать при помощи иерархического запроса

Нет, иерархический запрос тут не нужен, так как глубина вложенности (цитирования) всегда один.

Воспроизводимый [пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f74bbe5f395884bd4dd7307caace8524):

```
select p.userID, count (c.ID) quoted
from comments p outer apply (
    select c.id 
    from comments c
    where c.ParentID = p.ID) c
group by p.UserID
order by p.UserId
```

Результат:

```
    USERID     QUOTED
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          0
         3          0
         4          2
```

Answer (score 2):

Такой запрос сделает то, что вам нужно:

```
SELECT p.User_ID, count(c.ID)
FROM comments p
  LEFT JOIN comments c ON (c.Parent_Comment_ID = p.ID)
GROUP BY p.User_ID
```